# Angular Promise Error

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. Correct me if i am doing this wrong about promise.

```
doSomething(x)
{
    console.log(x);
}

var something = 0;
$http.post('/url')
   .then(function (response) {
      something = response.data;
})

doSomething(something);
```

assuming that variable something has value.. 
everytime i log it in the console inside the doSomething method. the value 
i receive is always 0;

what i did is put the method inside the then clause.
and i get the right value.

```
var something = 0;
$http.post('/url')
   .then(function (response) {
      something = response.data;
      doSomething(something);
})
```

is this 2nd code right? or did i miss something in my first code?

thanks

Comment: I believe `$http.post` takes at least two parameters: your url, data to send (and config/headers). If you just want to **get** the data from backend, use `$http.get`

Comment: the second snippet of code is the right one

Comment: the _second code_ is right because it's within a promise - asynchronous callback. You never know when the data will arrive, so it can execute `doSomething(something);` in your first case before it populates `something` in the promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your second code is right. Because $http returns a promise and that can take n time to return so it never goes in the .then instead the next statement is triggered.**

So, if suppose now you want to do something like your first code then you can use $q service. Like so (But, I won't recommend doing it here as it is not needed here).

```
doSomething(x)
{
    console.log(x);
}

var defer = $q.defer();
$http.post('/url')
   .then(function (response) {
      defer.resolve(response.data);
},function (err) {
      defer.reject(err);
});

defer.promise.then((data)=>{
 doSomething(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks. seems 2nd code is the proper usage for promise.